# Eclipse keeps changing the name of a file on startup

Tags: java, eclipse

My eclipse keeps changing the name of a file after restarting.

I have the file: 
*NotificationMciService.java*

```
public class NotificationMCIService{
    // Lots of code
}
```

When I refactor the filename to *NotificationMCIService.java* and restart eclipse, the filename changes back to *NotificationMciService.java*

What could possibly cause this?

Comment: When you refactor it in eclipse, can you navigate to the file on the file system and verify that it was actually changed?

Comment: What file system are you on?

Comment: when you refactor NotificationMciService.java to NotificationMCIService.java, check that changes get reflected to actual file present at Physical location by going to drive where actually file is present,  if it changed there then such things should not happen.

Comment: I'm running windows. I know windows normally isn't case sensitive and I've checked before if it changes the filename on the actual filesystem, and it DOES.. It actually changes the 'Mci' to 'MCI'. But it still manages to revert that change when I restart eclipse. I know.. It's a very odd (and annoying) problem.

Answer (score 2):

Windows is not case sensitive but it is case retentive.  Refactor the file into something with a completely different name and then back into the correct name with the intended case.

Comment: Is there anything about the file that you've not mentioned?  Like where it physically is, or whether it's under source control with a different case?

Comment: yes it's under SVN source control but that shouldn't really be an issue since I haven't updated the file in a while.

Comment: Humor me on this one.  What case is the filename on the SVN server?

Answer (score 0):

Got still this problem? Here's how I did it:

1. If you have the "auto-renamed" file open in an Eclipse editor, close it
2. In the file tree pane to the left, right-click on the file and select "Refactor"
3. Change the filename to a different name, e.g. put an x before the name (NotificationMciService.java -> xNotificationMciService.java)
4. Check with Explorer to see if the filename change is reflected in the file system as well. If not, change the filename in explorer to match the new name
5. Repeat the procedure, this time using your "real" required filename.

Eclipse keeps the name of the files in its own reporitory and always reverts it back to the name it "knows". Unfortunately, casing is not honored here - not even on Linux where I am working on.